# Call terminal program automatically several times

Tags: macos, terminal

I have around 50 input files to a terminal program. The program takes one file as input at the time, prints some data and terminates.

When it has terminated, I run the program again with the next file and so on.

Is there a way to make this automatic—since this will take several hours and some file take a few minutes and some can take 1 hour—and save each data print in a file output_inputfile.txt?

I was thinking to have a file like

```
myprogram file-1
myprogram file-2
myprogram file-3
```

and execute it in some way.

Comment: Take an introductory tutorial to bash scripting. In a nutshell: yes, you can literally write that into a file, then run that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that via the shell scripting capability, e.g. have a look at this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html. You could just put them all in one directory and use this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/your/files         # go to the directory
for i in $( ls ); do           # for every file that 'ls' returns
  /path/to/your/program $i     # call your program
done
```